# Cant post with axios network error reaxt native to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-native

I made a flask backend and deploy to heroku. It is working when i made a get request and made a post with postman json data. But i cant post when i use axios or fetch in react-native app.

````
const url = 'https://test.herokuapp.com/list/add';
        const config = {
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            data: {
                "test":this.state.testdata
            },
        };
        const response = await axios.post(url, config)
        .then(function(res){
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('What happened? ' + error);
          });      ```
````

Comment: Don't `JSON.stringify` data and then try.

Comment: I used without also json same error. I removed json from question